# Android: Pass Intent to third party Android Service

Tags: android

Another app has a Service that runs in the background. I would like to create a new app to send a pending intent to this service to make the service do something. Can this be done in Android?

```
    Intent anyConnectIntent = new Intent("com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android.service.ACTION_WIDGET_CONNECT");
    anyConnectIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android.service", "com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android.service.VpnService"));
    PendingIntent anyConnectSender = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, anyConnectIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getMidnight().getTimeInMillis(), anyConnectSender);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if this service provider isn't blocking you with a permission.

See : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#prmsn

Comment: What if I know the permissions. Can I add it programmatically?

Comment: It depends on the permission level. See : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html